# Cannot install tor in Ubuntu bionic

Tags: apt, tor

When trying `apt update` there is error

```
E: The repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

and I cannot install tor. Any recommendation how to proceed please? I cannot upgrade Ubuntu because of other software.

Comment: Read this: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/installation/

Comment: Why aren't you using the Ubuntu packaged version in the repository?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tor&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: Remove the repository from the system by using instructions from duplicate answer.

Comment: "Why aren't you using the Ubuntu packaged version in the repository?" - I am sorry I am rather an user than administrator, I do not know how to install package from internet repository

Comment: The guide at tb-manual.torproject.org/installation is for tor browser. I do not have graphical gui and I want to install tor and hidden services, not tor browser